# bashrc access and configuration

Tags: bash, configuration, gmail

I'm trying to set up gmail configuration and mail chimp config on my new ruby dev environment.

I access `.bashrc` with `~/.bashrc`

I use the following commands:

```
Karans-MacBook-Air:~ KaranSatia$ export GMAIL_USERNAME="ksatia@gmail.com"
Karans-MacBook-Air:~ KaranSatia$ export GMAIL_PASSWORD="'...!'"
-bash: !'": event not found
```

Any advice?

I thought that by using both double and single quotation marks around my password (which contains an exclamation point), I would bypass the issue of using a special character. This doesn't seem to be the case. Am I even in the correct directory? Using the command `~/.bashrc` seemed to work. It didn't do anything, and the terminal showed that I was in the same location. Do I need to be in the specific app directory in order to do this?

Comment: Seems I had to escape the exclamation point...this wasn't even listed in the tutorial I'm using. What a pain.

Comment: Single quotes inside double quotes aren't special. Use just single quotes. Escaping the exclamation point doesn't actually work correctly (it leaves the escaping slash in place). `echo "foo\!bar"` -> `foo\!bar`.

Answer (score 1):

In an interactive bash session, the `!` signals some kind of history substitution: you may have to temporarily turn it off:

```
$ echo "foo!bar"
bash: !bar": event not found
$ set +H
$ echo "foo!bar"
foo!bar
$ set -H
```

Or just use single quotes

```
$ echo 'foo!bar'
foo!bar
```

Refs:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction